# Plotting multiple graphs from a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a pandas dataframe `A`,`B`, and `pos`and want to plot `A` versus `B` but in such a way that a distinct graph is generated for each value of `pos`.

Meaning a single figure but a graph for all `pos = 1`, one for `pos = 2` and so on

The dataframe is structured like this:

```
      A   B    pos 

1     6   2     1
2     2   10    2
3     1   3     4
4     8   1     1
5     6   1     1
```

How do I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a scatter plot. Other types can be defiened using the `kind` keyword.

To genearate 3 figures based on the number in `pos`, use

```
s.groupby('pos').plot(x='A', y='B', kind='scatter')
```

.

If you want to collect all three plots in one figure, then I think the best solution is to create a 'color'-column in the source to define the colors by group.

Data the looks like this:

```
1  6   2    1    red
2  2  10    2   blue
3  1   3    4  green
4  8   1    1    red
5  6   1    1    red
```

This is working:

```
s.plot(x='A', y='B', kind='scatter', color=s['color'].values)
```

And this is also working [documented here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

```
s.plot(x='A', y='B', kind='scatter', c='color')
```

**Output**
[image: Scatter by ginven data]

**Comment**
Unfortunately this is not supported and raises an error.

```
s.plot(x='A', y='B', kind='scatter', color='color')
```

But in my option ths would be most straight forward.